# switch case loop statement

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement

I am having a problem with my one assignment. I made one function name `chequingsaving` and when I call this function, it prints some data which is correct, but when I entered character depends on my selection of account it directly goes out of the loop. If I entered a correct character value, then same thing happens. That function code is below. Help me to find out my mistake. The thing is I also used a switch case, but still it directly goes to default. Same thing happens with if/else loop.

```
void chequingsaving()  /*Chequing and saving account function*/
{
    char a;
    double r, Initialamount = 0;
    printf(" c) Chequing\n");
    printf(" s) Savings\n");
    printf("Which account would you like to use?\n");
    scanf("% c", &a);

    if (a == 'c' || a == 'C')
        {
            printf("Please enter the amount for deposit\n");
            scanf("% lf", &r);
            Initialamount = Initialamount + r;
            printf("Your chequing account balance is=%lf", Initialamount);
        }
    else
        if (a == 's' || a == 'S')
        {
            printf("Please enter the amount for deposit\n");
            scanf("%lf", &r);
            Initialamount = Initialamount + r;
            printf("Your chequing account balance is=%lf", Initialamount);
        }
        else

        printf("Invalid character\n");

}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the value of a when it enters the if/else statements?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space in `scanf`:

```
scanf("%c", &a);
```

and also in the following `scanf`:

```
scanf("%lf", &r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf is not correct, you have space "% c".